# Implementation of Facebook Graph Api Search in Android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

How to implement Facebook Graph Api Search in Android. When i passed any search query it says Unsupported get request.
Any Suggestions.

Comment: Many you do not permission to access it.

Comment: I gave the publish permission..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
GET graph.facebook.com /search? q={your-query}& type={object-type}
```

For more follow below link

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to the official documentation provided by facebook https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.5

It provides exhaustive information for facebook graph API.